# Can't record Old Game with sound with MSI Afterburner

Tags: audio-hardware, recording, streaming, midtown-madness-2

I have an old PC game called Midtown Madness 2, an old 2000 game, that I desperately want to record to make a Machinima. No recording program could record without rendering issues. I tried several recording programs and they all could record sound, but have a black screen or extremely low framerate. I stumbled upon MSI Afterburner as I have an MSI card. I recorded it with the recorder that came with the program and it recorded AMAZING! 60 fps at 720p no rendering issues or framerate loss! The only problem is there is NO SOUND! I tested it with another game Need For Speed Most Wanted (2005) and it recorded very well with no framerate loss and it had SOUND too!

So I think the problem is in the game. I tried every sound option in the game.

- Digital Audio
- Speakers
- Primary Sound Driver

None of them worked when recording, but I could hear sound from my speaker in all of the options.

I'm thinking I should just have no sounds and just add my own sounds in a video editor. I would really like to hear the sounds from the game in the video, because I want to hear engine sounds and stuff.

Comment: Are you using an AMD or nVIDIA card?

Comment: I have an AMD 7750 2gb

Comment: What other recorders you tried using?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this problem is because the game is so old.
You could try using another recorder just to catch the sounds and then edit together, but thats more of a hack than anything...

Comment: If I use 2 recorders at once, it would use too much resources.

Comment: Answers are only for answering the question, not discussion or requests for further information. To ask for more information about a question, please use comments instead. In the meantime I've removed your question from the answer and left it as a comment on the question.